# Value returns to 0 after candle close

Tags: pine-script

Im trying to plot the percentage change from previous daily close to current price.  Everything works fine, but when a new candle closes the value returns to 0 and only plots the current bar change instead of the daily change.  If I refresh the page then its back to normal, until another candle closes.

```
study("Percent change from daily", precision=2)
a = input(title="Symbol", type=input.symbol, defval="ftx:btcperp")
b = input(title="Resolution", type=input.resolution, defval="D")
c = security(a, b, close)
d = (close - c[1]) / c[1] * 100
plot(d)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This calculates the ROC between the chart's `close` and the non-repainting HTF value fetched with the `security()` call, which is the close of the last completed day of symbol `a`:

```
//@version=4
study("Percent change from daily", precision=2)
a = input(title="Symbol", type=input.symbol, defval="ftx:btcperp")
b = input(title="Resolution", type=input.resolution, defval="D")

f_security(_sym, _res, _src, _rep) => security(_sym, _res, _src[not _rep and barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0])[_rep or barstate.isrealtime ? 0 : 1]
// Non-repainting HTF value.
c = f_security(a, b, close, false)
d = (close - c) / c * 100
plot(d)
```